# Sending websocket message in Go lambda function

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, websocket, aws-lambda

I have two Go functions:

```golang
func NewAPIGatewaySession() *apigatewaymanagementapi.ApiGatewayManagementApi {
    sesh := session.Must(session.NewSessionWithOptions(session.Options{
        SharedConfigState: session.SharedConfigEnable,
    }))
    return apigatewaymanagementapi.New(sesh)
}
```

and

```golang
func SendWsMessage(connectionID string, msgData []byte) error {
    connectionInput := &apigatewaymanagementapi.PostToConnectionInput{
        ConnectionId: aws.String(connectionID),
        Data:         msgData,
    }
    _, err := NewAPIGatewaySession().PostToConnection(connectionInput)
    return err
}
```

But unfortunately I am getting the error:

> RequestError: send request failed
> caused by: Post "https://execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/@connections/GN5OCf-coAMCElw%3D": dial tcp: lookup execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com on 169.254.78.1:53: no such host

This code is inside a Docker image lambda function. I am not sure if this is some sort of DNS error (but probably not if it has found out "169.254.78.1")?

Comment: 169.254... is link local... it's your lambda's dns server I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Your lambda function needs to know what is the exact endpoint address of AWS Gateway management API. You can configure the address of the endpoint like this.

```golang
api := apigatewaymanagementapi.New(session)
api.Endpoint = "https://xxxxxxx.execute-api.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/prod"
```

Endpoint address can be found in AWS console in API Gateway configuration under **API** -> **Stage** -> **Connection URL**.